# how would I know the difference when rejecting null hypothesis

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

```
wilcox.test(data$personal_sex, data$dwelling_problems_safety, mu=0, alt="two.sided", conf.int=T, conf.level =0.95, paired=F, exact=F, na.action = na.omit)
```

My Hypothesis is :
H0 : Male = Female
H1 : Male not equal to female

So my question is when, I reject the null hypothesis and accept that the difference in male and female is there, how do I interpret the male and female difference which gender has more effect on the hypothesis?

Comment: Why is the [tag:regression] being used here? The [Wilcoxon signed-rank test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) does not simply test the difference in the original variables.

Comment: Are you sure you want the `wilcox.test` and not the `t.test`?

Comment: Which gender has the greater effect in the data?  That's your answer.

Comment: Your call to `wilcox.test`  is not going to be doing what you want it to.

Answer (score 2):

Since the hypothesis is about the *difference* between males and females, it is not really possible to say that one gender had "more effect" on the hypothesis ---i.e., more effect on the difference.  As an analogy, if I say there is 2.5 years difference in age between me and my brother, it would be silly to then ask which of our ages had the most effect on this age difference.